# remap barycentric coordinates to distance from triangle dual

Tags: math, geometry

I have a set of points inside triangle in barycentric coordinates. I want to remap these to effectively produce the dual graph of the triangle

so that for an interpolated value, both the centre point (1/3,1/3,1/3) through to either of the triangle edges (e.g 1/2,0,1/2) should equal 0.

> before an after image of a triangle interpolating between red, green
>   and blue, with the second triangle exhibiting a dark dual graph 'Y'
>   shape across it.   [image]

I realise that I could solve this by further tessellating the triangle and recalculating the barycentres, but I would prefer to avoid that if I can.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course, walk away for half an hour and you find the answer. For a given barycentric coordinate:

1. Sort the weights in descending order
2. Take the highest weight. Put all others in a different list.
3. Subtract the second highest weight from the highest weight.
4. Use this value as a multiplier to get the result you desire.